# No qualifying Bean found error after adding AOP feature to a Spring project

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I get the below error while adding AOP feature to my simple project can someone shed light over it for me?
I also mentioned related part of the code in the following.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.AOP.Car' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:337)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1123)
    at com.AOP.App.main(App.java:13)
```

---

```
package com.AOP;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;    
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.AOP")
public class AppConfig {        
}
```

---

```
package com.AOP;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Car car =  context.getBean(Car.class);      
        car.drive();
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.AOP;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Car implements Vehicle{

    @Autowired
    private Tyre tyre;      
    public Tyre getTyre() {
        return tyre;
    }

    public void setTyre(Tyre tyre) {
        this.tyre = tyre;
    }

    public void drive()
    {
        System.out.println("driving a car");
        System.out.println(tyre);
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.AOP;

public interface Vehicle {
    void drive();

}
```

---

```
package com.AOP;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
@Aspect
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AOPClass {

    @After("execution(* setT*(..))")    
    public void afterAdvice2()
    {
        System.out.println("After Advise (set) start here");
    }

    @Before("execution(* drive(..))")   
    public void beforeAdvice1()
    {
        System.out.println("Before Advise (drive) start here");
    }
}
```

---

If I get a simple class "Car" without implementing the "Vehicle" interface , every thing works fine. But adding that extension will cause the menterror.

Comment: Your ComponentScan declares a different base package than the one the components are actually in?

Comment: And the error message complains about `com.Aop.Car`, but the name of the class is `com.AOP.Car`. Post your actual code, and your actual error message.

Comment: Sorry, that was my problem with shortening the package name to post here. In the project all is well as you guys mentioned.

Comment: Read https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-proxies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is well described in [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-proxying).
Your case is exactly:

> If the target object to be proxied implements at least one interface, a JDK dynamic proxy is used.

You can still get the bean by name, and see what is its class:

```
    Object b = context.getBean("car");      
    System.out.println(b.getClass().getName());
```

It will be something like `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38`, and if you try to browse its interfaces, there will be `com.AOP.Vehicle` among them.

At this point, it is clear why it is impossible to get the bean by class.

What to do ? There are some options:

- Make `Car` do not implement `Vehicle` (any interface). This way, bean will be proxified by CGLIB (and its class remains unchanged), and your code will work
- Force use CGLIB-proxies everywhere by adding following property to annotation `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)`. Your code will work
- Get bean by its name (see code above)
- Get bean(s) by interface:

```
    Vehicle car =  context.getBean(Vehicle.class);      
    car.drive();
```